# FOS Elastica: How can I populate an index without Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

I use FOS Elastica bundle in my Symfony application but I am not using Doctrine. I try to populate the Elasticsearch with a custom provider. Here is my code.

```yaml
# config/packages/fos_elastica.yaml

fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        my_index:
            use_alias: true
            properties:
                my_property:
                    type: keyword
            persistence:
                provider:
                    service: app.search_provider.my_provider
                listener: false
```

```yaml
# config/services.yaml

services:
    # ...

    app.search_provider.my_provider:
        class: App\SearchProvider\MyProvider
        tags:
            - { name: fos_elastica.pager_provider, index: my_index, type: my_type }
```

```php
<?php

// src/SearchProvider/MyProvider.php

namespace App\SearchProvider;

use Elastica\Document;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Provider\PagerfantaPager;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Provider\PagerInterface;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Provider\PagerProviderInterface;
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta;

final class MyProvider implements PagerProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(array $options = []): PagerInterface
    {
        $document = new Document();

        $document->setData([
            'my_property' => 'test',
        ]);

        return new PagerfantaPager(new Pagerfanta(new ArrayAdapter([$document])));
    }
}
```

When I use the command `bin/console fos:elastica:populate` I get the following error

```
FOS\ElasticaBundle\Persister\ObjectPersister::__construct(): Argument #3 ($objectClass) must be of type string, null given
```

Also I am wondering how I can index a great number of documents. I think they would be too much to store in an array. Is there a way to use a callback instead of an array in `new Pagerfanta` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I need a DTO to use as a model. The following code works:

```yaml
# config/packages/fos_elastica.yaml

fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        my_index:
            use_alias: true
            properties:
                myProperty:
                    type: keyword
            persistence:
                model: App\Entity\MyEntity
                provider:
                    service: app.search_provider.my_provider
                listener: false
```

```php
// src/Entity

namespace App\Entity;

final class MyEntity
{
    public int $id;

    public string $myProperty;
}
```

```php
// src/SearchProvider/MyProvider.php

namespace App\SearchProvider;

use App\Entity\MyEntity;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Provider\PagerfantaPager;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Provider\PagerInterface;
use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Provider\PagerProviderInterface;
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta;

final class MyProvider implements PagerProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(array $options = []): PagerInterface
    {
        $myEntity = new MyEntity();

        $myEntity->id = 1;
        $myEntity->myProperty = 'test';

        return new PagerfantaPager(new Pagerfanta(new ArrayAdapter([$myEntity])));
    }
}
```

But I still have a problem with indexing a large set of data. I think I can not create an array with millions of elements.